# AsyncTask as kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines

Typical use for AsyncTask: I want to run a task in another thread and after that task is done, I want to perform some operation in my UI thread, namely hiding a progress bar.

The task is to be started in `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureAvailable` and after it finished I want to hide the progress bar. Doing this synchronously does not work because it would block the thread building the UI, leaving the screen black, not even showing the progress bar I want to hide afterwards.

So far I use this:

```
inner class MyTask : AsyncTask<ProgressBar, Void, ProgressBar>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: ProgressBar?) : ProgressBar {
        // do async
        return params[0]!!
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: ProgressBar?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        result?.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

But these classes are beyond ugly so I'd like to get rid of them.
I'd like to do this with kotlin coroutines. I've tried some variants but none of them seem to work. The one I would most likely suspect to work is this:

```
runBlocking {
        // do async
}
progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
```

But this does not work properly. As I understand it, the `runBlocking`does not start a new thread, as `AsyncTask` would, which is what I need it to do. But using the `thread` coroutine, I don't see a reasonable way to get notified when it finished. Also, I can't put `progressBar.visibility = View.GONE` in a new thread either, because only the UI thread is allowed to make such operations.

I'm new to coroutines so I don't quite understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: Benjamin Basmaci, do you still think accepted answer is correct? Maybe you would reconsider your choice because it seems the question is popular and users seeking answers may get confused.

Comment: @Sergey Thank you very much for your answers and your comments.
Im sure you helped a lot of peope and it shows in the upvotes obviously.
I changed the accepted answer, but I didnt pick either of your answers.
The reason is, that I specifically wanted to have a slim, quick solution that didnt involve writing new classes for every use-case I have. For that reason, I made an own answer and accepted that one, as that is what I am currently doing.
Not sure about the pros and cons of the two approaches, but thats what I was looking for with this question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To use a coroutine you need a couple of things:

- Implement **CoroutineScope** interface.
- References to **Job** and **CoroutineContext** instances.
- Use **suspend** function modifier to suspend a coroutine without blocking the **Main Thread** when calling function that runs code in **Background Thread**.
- Use **withContext(Dispatchers.IO)** function to run code in background thread and **launch** function to start a coroutine.

Usually I use a separate class for that, e.g. **"Presenter" or "ViewModel"**:

```
class Presenter : CoroutineScope {
    private var job: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job // to run code in Main(UI) Thread

    // call this method to cancel a coroutine when you don't need it anymore,
    // e.g. when user closes the screen
    fun cancel() {
        job.cancel()
    }

    fun execute() = launch {
        onPreExecute()
        val result = doInBackground() // runs in background thread without blocking the Main Thread
        onPostExecute(result)
    }

    private suspend fun doInBackground(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // to run code in Background Thread
        // do async work
        delay(1000) // simulate async work
        return@withContext "SomeResult"
    }

    // Runs on the Main(UI) Thread
    private fun onPreExecute() {
        // show progress
    }

    // Runs on the Main(UI) Thread
    private fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
        // hide progress
    }
}
```

With [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) the code is more concise using `viewModelScope`:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    fun execute() = viewModelScope.launch {
        onPreExecute()
        val result = doInBackground() // runs in background thread without blocking the Main Thread
        onPostExecute(result)
    }

    private suspend fun doInBackground(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // to run code in Background Thread
        // do async work
        delay(1000) // simulate async work
        return@withContext "SomeResult"
    }

    // Runs on the Main(UI) Thread
    private fun onPreExecute() {
        // show progress
    }

    // Runs on the Main(UI) Thread
    private fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
        // hide progress
    }
}
```

To use `viewModelScope` add next line to dependencies of the app's **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION"
```

At the time of writing `final LIFECYCLE_VERSION = "2.3.0-alpha04"`

---

[Here is also implementation of Async Task using Kotlin coroutines and extension function on `CoroutineScope`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62748880/1731626).

Answer (score 18):

Another approach is to create generic extension function on `CoroutineScope`:

```
fun <R> CoroutineScope.executeAsyncTask(
        onPreExecute: () -> Unit,
        doInBackground: () -> R,
        onPostExecute: (R) -> Unit
) = launch {
    onPreExecute()
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // runs in background thread without blocking the Main Thread
        doInBackground()
    }
    onPostExecute(result)
}
```

Now we can use it with any `CoroutineScope`:

- In [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

  ```
    class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

        fun someFun() {
            viewModelScope.executeAsyncTask(onPreExecute = {
                // ...
            }, doInBackground = {
                // ...
                "Result" // send data to "onPostExecute"
            }, onPostExecute = {
                // ... here "it" is a data returned from "doInBackground"
            })
        }
    }
  ```
- In `Activity` or `Fragment`:

  ```
    lifecycleScope.executeAsyncTask(onPreExecute = {
        // ...
    }, doInBackground = {
        // ...
        "Result" // send data to "onPostExecute"
    }, onPostExecute = {
        // ... here "it" is a data returned from "doInBackground"
    })
  ```

To use `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope` add next line(s) to dependencies of the app's **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION" // for viewModelScope
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION" // for lifecycleScope
```

At the time of writing `final LIFECYCLE_VERSION = "2.3.0-alpha05"`.

Comment: best solution to maintain familiarity. can you perhaps add a java version for this? I tried to decompile this from kotlin but the resulting code looks garbage.

Comment: @chitgoks This implementation is based on Coroutines, Java doesn't have Coroutines, so it is hard to do the same in Java.

Comment: i love you man! i think i really understood coroutines only after reading this snippet

Answer (score 5):

You can get ProgressBar to run on the UI Main Thread, while using coroutine to run your task asynchronously.

Inside your override fun onCreate() method,

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { // Coroutine Dispatcher confined to Main UI Thread
    yourTask() // your task implementation
}
```

You can initialize,

```
private var jobStart: Job? = null
```

> In Kotlin, var declaration means the property is mutable. If you
>   declare it as val, it is immutable, read-only & cannot be reassigned.

Outside the onCreate() method, yourTask() can be implemented as a suspending function, which does not block main caller thread.

When the function is suspended while waiting for the result to be returned, its running thread is unblocked for other functions to execute.

```
private suspend fun yourTask() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default){ // with a given coroutine context
    jobStart = launch {
       try{
        // your task implementation
       } catch (e: Exception) {
             throw RuntimeException("To catch any exception thrown for yourTask", e)
      }
    }
  }
```

For your progress bar, you can create a button to show the progress bar when the button is clicked.

```
buttonRecognize!!.setOnClickListener {
    trackProgress(false)
}
```

Outside of onCreate(),

```
private fun trackProgress(isCompleted:Boolean) {
    buttonRecognize?.isEnabled = isCompleted // ?. safe call
    buttonRecognize!!.isEnabled // !! non-null asserted call

    if(isCompleted) {
        loading_progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        loading_progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

> An additional tip is to check that your coroutine is indeed running on
>   another thread, eg. DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,
>
> ```
> Log.e("yourTask", "Running on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
> ```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to run coroutine with `launch(context)`, not with `runBlocking`:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html

Second, to get the effect of `onPostExecute`, you have to use

[Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))
or [View.post(Runnable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: There is no need to use `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) or View.post(Runnable).`. Using appropriate `Dispatchers` you can just call function in UI thread. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58900195/1731626

Answer (score 1):

This does not use coroutines, but it's a quick solution to have a task run in background and do something on UI after that.

I'm not sure about the pros and cons of this approach compared to the others, but it works and is super easy to understand:

```
Thread {
    // do the async Stuff
    runOnUIThread {
        // do the UI stuff
    }
    // maybe do some more stuff
}.start()
```

With this solution, you can easily pass values and objects between the two entities. You can also nest this indefinitely.

Comment: It is not a good solution. You may have background task executing a long time, meanwhile your activity can be destroyed and you may have exceptions when calling `runOnUiThread ` method. BTW this solution is not using coroutines.

Comment: @Sergey 
Although I do not agree with the reasoning about the risks of this approach, I reviewed the question and answers.
Although the question was aiming at a solution like mine, thats now how it was written. Reason for that was my then lack of understanding kotlin, android and coroutines. That inexperience led me to ask for coroutines specifically.
As you said, this question is popular and my solution does not involve coroutines.
My initial intent and the exact wording of the question are very different. However, the wording is what counts. So I will reassign accepted solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following approach might be able to suffice your needs. It requires less boilerplate code and works for 100% of usecases

```
GlobalScope.launch {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream())

            }.invokeOnCompletion {
                createNotification()
            }
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use `GlobalScope`. from the documentation: "...Using async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope is highly discouraged."

Answer (score 0):

```
private val TAG = MainActivity::class.simpleName.toString()
    private var job = Job()

    //coroutine Exception
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        Log.d(TAG, "$exception handled !")
    }

    //coroutine context
    val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext get() = Dispatchers.Main + job + handler

    //coroutine scope
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)




    fun execute() = coroutineScope.launch {
        onPreExecute()
        val result = doInBackground() // runs in background thread without blocking the Main Thread
        onPostExecute(result)
    }


    private suspend fun doInBackground(): String =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // to run code in Background Thread
            // do async work
            //delay(5000) // simulate async work
            loadFileFromStorage()
            return@withContext "SomeResult"
        }

    // Runs on the Main(UI) Thread
    private fun onPreExecute() {
        LoadingScreen.displayLoadingWithText(this,"Loading Files",false)

    }

    // Runs on the Main(UI) Thread
    private fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
        //progressDialogDialog?.dismiss()
        LoadingScreen.hideLoading()
        // hide progress
    }
```

Comment: Aside from this answer being very close to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58900195/4687402), it is missing some important explanations as to what is happening and how it is different from the accepted answer. As it shares a lot of its code, that distinction should be made clear. Please add some explanation for this approach and how it differs from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I started migrating my `AsyncTask` stuff in my Android Project to using coroutines...and if you just really need to do something on the UI after completing the async task (i.e., you're just overriding doInBackGround and onPostExecute in AsyncTask)...something like this can be done (i tried this myself and it works):

```kotlin
val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
    val rc = ...
    return@async rc
}

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val job_rc = job.await() // whatever job returns is fed to job_rc

    // do UI updates here
}
```

The job that you have doesn't need to use the I/O Dispatcher...you can just use the default if it's not I/O intensive.

however the the coroutine waiting for the job to complete needs to be in on the Main/UI thread so you can update UI.

Yes, there's some syntax sugar that can be used to make the above code look more cool but this is at least easier to grasp when one is just starting to migrate to using coroutines.