# Class Doesn't Return A MutableMap Object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, mutablemap

I was using Kotlin to make a basic Currency converter app with an API. To download information, I have created a new class called DownloadTaskClass that extends the deprecated AsyncTask class (I haven't learned the other classes of the java.util.concurrent package).

The DownloadTaskClass contains a method to return a MutableMap to the MainActivity. However, I cannot understand why this method isn't returning the MutableMap object. Here are the classes.

**DownloadTaskClass.kt**

```
package com.example.kotlincurrency

import android.os.AsyncTask
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.lang.Exception
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL

class DownloadTaskClass: AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    private var data: Int = 0
    private var result: String = ""
    private var mutableMap: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()

    private lateinit var url: URL
    private lateinit var inputStream: InputStream
    private lateinit var inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader
    private lateinit var httpURLConnection: HttpURLConnection

    override fun doInBackground(vararg urls: String): String? {
        url = URL(urls[0])
        httpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        inputStream = httpURLConnection.inputStream
        inputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
        data = inputStreamReader.read()

        while (data != -1){
            val current: Char = data.toChar()
            result += current
            data = inputStreamReader.read()
        }

        return result
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        try {
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(result)
            mutableMap["date"] = jsonObject.getString("date")
            
            val rates: String = jsonObject.getString("rates")
            val currencyJSONObject = JSONObject(rates)
            mutableMap["USD"] = currencyJSONObject.getString("USD")
            mutableMap["GBP"] = currencyJSONObject.getString("GBP")
            mutableMap["EUR"] = currencyJSONObject.getString("EUR")
            mutableMap["CHF"] = currencyJSONObject.getString("CHF")
            mutableMap["SEK"] = currencyJSONObject.getString("SEK")
            mutableMap["CAD"] = currencyJSONObject.getString("CAD")
        }

        catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun returnMapMethod(): MutableMap<String, Any>{
        return mutableMap
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.kotlincurrency

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setActionBar()
        downloadInitInfo()
    }

    private fun setActionBar() {
        supportActionBar!!.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.setCustomView(R.layout.layout_action_bar)
    }

    private fun downloadInitInfo(){
        val downloadTaskClass = DownloadTaskClass()
        downloadTaskClass.execute("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=INR")
        println(downloadTaskClass.returnMapMethod())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make an asynchronous request in `doInBackground()` method, it may take some time before `onPostExecute()` is called and `mutableMap` is filled with data. When you call `returnMapMethod()` method `mutableMap` object hasn't been filled with data yet. You need to use some listener to be notified when the data is loaded.

Here is an example of using `LiveData` to observe data:

```
class DownloadTaskClass: AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    
    private var data: MutableLiveData<MutableMap<String, Any>> = MutableLiveData()

    // ...
    
    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        // ...
        data.value = mutableMap
    }

    fun returnMapMethod(): LiveData<out Map<String, Any>> {
        return data
    }
}
```

In your Activity:

```
private fun downloadInitInfo(){
    val downloadTaskClass = DownloadTaskClass()
    downloadTaskClass.execute("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=INR")
    downloadTaskClass.returnMapMethod().observe(this, Observer { 
        println(it) // "it" contains the `mutableMap` data
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually, this mutableMap object that I'm returning from the DownloadTaskClass will be used in my MainActivity as soon as the app starts. And I don't want it to take a lot of time before it is returned. Is there some way to achieve this without LiveData? I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: You can use some listener. Or you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62542551/1731626  to create an alternative of `AsyncTask`. Good luck!

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.